# Excel string split on html tags

Tags: string, excel

I am searching since a while for a solution to this and I am sure it exists. I came close but I am simply not able to get it working:

I have a excel file with a list of products and their 3 selling points in html.

A1 contains the string:

```
<li>Sellingpoint1</li><li>Sellingpoint2</li><li>Sellingpoint3</li>
```

I need to reuse the content in another way and would like to split the selling points and remove the html:

B1 should be: Sellingpoint1
C1 should be: Sellingpoint2
D1 should be: Sellingpoint3

I have tried with following solutions which I found on this forum: 
In B1 enter the formula

```
=IF(ISERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND(";",A1)-1)),A1,LEFT(A1,FIND(";",A1)-1))
```

In C1 enter the formula

```
=IF(ISERROR(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(";",A1))),"",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(";",A1)))
```

Could anyone please help me to get this working

Comment: very poor description Check this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why are you searching for semicolons `";"` in the string when none exist in your sample?  I think before using a solution that you find here or elsewhere, you need to understand how it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A2, "</", ""), "li>", REPT(" ", LEN($A2))), LEN($A2)*((COLUMN(A:A)-1)*2+1), LEN($A2)))
```

Fill right as necessary.

[image: selling_point]

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:
Select Entire data -> Go to data tab -> Text to Columns -> Select Delimited -> Next -> Check Other  and write "/" in box -> Finish